# $X^*$ separable implies separable unit ball

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces, separable-spaces

Let $X$ be the dual space of a normed space $X$ and let $X^*$ be separable. Prove that $S^* = \left\{F \in X^* : ||F|| = 1\right\}$ is separable.

**My solution** : suppose $Y$ is a dense countable set in $X^*$, it is enough to  prove that $Y \cap S^*$ is dense in $S^*$ . This is true because $\overline{Y \cap S^*} = \overline{Y} \cap S^* = X^* \cap S^* = S^*$.

Is it that simple or am I missing something?

If this is correct, which I doubt, it would mean that every subset of the separable space $X^*$ is separable.

Comment: $Y\cap S^*$ could be empty.

Comment: But, a metric space is separable iff it is second countable, and second countability is hereditary.

Comment: I think you have quoted the question wrongly. What is interesting is that the set is a weak* separable metric space.

Comment: Every subspace of a separable metric space is separable. But one needs to do a little more work to prove that.